# Manga where the girl is physically strong and is assisting a god with finding believers

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga quite a few years back online (mangafox maybe?) but I think it was ongoing/unfinished. The main character is a physically strong girl known for breaking things (nicknamed something along the lines of the “god of breaking things”) and ends up having to help an actual fallen/unknown god gain followers and believers. I believe he also had an attendant of some sort. Genre was definitely shoujo romance.

Iit was black and white! Her hair, I think, was blonde, but because it was black and white (and the nature of some mangakas choices) it could have been just light brown.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Seirei Produce](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/seirei-produce), a Japanese manga from 2009. There are only 10 chapters; it looks like it was cancelled after that.

> Shiina Momose doesn't believe in fortune telling and the occult, but **for some reason, she can destroy anything with a touch**. One day while on her way to school, a young man approaches her and claims to be a God. Furthermore, he believes that he was guided towards her and for that reason he has become convinced that **she should become his first follower**!

The female lead, Shiina Momose, has the nickname "god of destruction" as seen in the below image. She doesn't appear to be physically strong, just cursed to have things break around her. She is approached by a minor god and his attendant and asked to become his first follower.

[image]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag "God-Human relationship" and filtering to Shoujo Romance Manga.